# How to include http://www in my url always

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, nginx

I'm running a site using nginx with the laravel framework and im not sure how to make my url include http://www in my url always. Currently it is just domain.com but I want it to be http://www.domain.com

If i use www.domain.com or domain.com it works but domain.com will not redirect to www.domain.com.

I also want to always include http:// in my url.

Would I have to change this is nginx, laravel or my .htaccess file and what changes do I need. This is my nginx/sites-available-default file

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/laravel/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #


        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

And this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  www.example.org  example.org;
            if ($http_host = example.org) {
                rewrite  (.*)  http://www.example.org$1;
        }
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml applicati$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: you use apache2+nginx? or one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You need use 301 Redirect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Instruction for nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.org  example.org;
    if ($http_host = example.org) {
        rewrite  (.*)  http://www.example.org$1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Instruction for apache:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  example.org
RewriteRule  (.*)          http://www.example.org$1
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Comment: I'm using nginx. This didnt work for me unfortunately. I just copy paste the code in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and replace example.org with my domain name and restart nginx, correct?

Comment: Got it to redirect correctly but now I just get the Welcome to nginx! screen

Comment: Show your full config

Comment: sorry for the late response. I have included the.conf file in my original post

Comment: you need add that section to `sites-available/default` instead site.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using .htaccess file.

You have to write rewrite rule in your .htaccess file as follow

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Add this code in your .htaccess file and you are done.